# How to get max average value and max timestamp

Tags: mysql, eloquent, aggregate-functions

**Question:** How to get best 3 organization, and its latest review together with related data?
**Question2:** How to implement this query in Laravel Eloquent

*best organization = the one with best average Grade in table review*

*latest review = the review with max timestamp but must be review of this specific organization*

*related data = data of tables Address, City, Country, Activity, User->only Name, Surname, Id*

[image: Table schema]

so far I got this:

```
SELECT *, AVG(r.General) as average, COUNT(r.BuyerId) as countBuyer, COUNT(r.SupplierId) as countSupplier, COUNT(r.EmployeeId) as countEmployee, COUNT(r.OtherId) as countOther, COUNT(r.Id) as countReview
FROM organization as o 
INNER JOIN review as r ON o.Id = r.OrganizationId 
INNER JOIN user as u ON u.Id = r.UserId
INNER JOIN address as a ON a.Id = o.AddressId
INNER JOIN city as c ON c.Id = a.CityId
INNER JOIN country as co ON co.Id = c.CountryId
INNER JOIN activity as ac ON ac.Id = o.ActivityId
GROUP BY o.Id
ORDER BY `average` DESC  
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use '*' in such a query. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It kind of does, I am using the address, city, country, activity all the data from review, and some of the data from user. Maybe I can write it all down without Id taggs and such, but its still lots of data that I need

Comment: No. It doesn't. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem: `JOIN` operations cause combinatorial explosion -- many rows in your result set.  When you use `JOIN` operations with GROUP BY operations, lots of rows can be duplicated, so the sums, counts, and averages are all distorted by counting stuff more than once.

Also, `COUNT(some_column)` counts the non-null values in that column, and `COUNT(*)` counts all the rows. I think you may want `COUNT(DISTINCT BuyerId)` if you want to count, well, distinct buyers.

If you want clean aggregates from that `review` table, you need to compute them in a subquery.

```
              SELECT OrganizationID,
                     AVG(General) as average, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT BuyerId) as countBuyer, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT SupplierId) as countSupplier, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeId) as countEmployee, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT OtherId) as countOther, 
                     COUNT(*) as countReview
                FROM review
            GROUP BY OrganizationID   
            ORDER BY AVG(General) DESC
            LIMIT 3
```

This gives you a virtual table with one row per organization, showing the summary review data. It's limited to the top 3.

The latest review is trickier to get. This might work, as long as there aren't duplicate timestamps.

```
             SELECT r.*
               FROM review r
               JOIN (
                       SELECT OrganizationId,
                              MAX(Timestamp) Timestamp
                         FROM review
                        GROUP BY OrganizationId
                    ) maxts   ON r.OrganizationId = maxts.OrganizationId
                             AND r.Timestamp = maxts.Timestamp
```

You then join those virtual table to your other tables *as if it were a physical table* and you avoid the combinatorial explosion distortion of the aggregates.

```
   SELECT whatever, aggr.*, latest.*
     FROM organization as o
     JOIN (
              SELECT OrganizationID,
                     AVG(General) as average, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT BuyerId) as countBuyer, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT SupplierId) as countSupplier, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeId) as countEmployee, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT OtherId) as countOther, 
                     COUNT(*) as countReview
                FROM review
            GROUP BY OrganizationID   
            ORDER BY AVG(General) DESC
            LIMIT 3 
          ) aggr ON o.Id = aggr.OrganizationId
     JOIN (
             SELECT r.*
               FROM review r
               JOIN (
                       SELECT OrganizationId,
                              MAX(Timestamp) Timestamp
                         FROM review
                        GROUP BY OrganizationId
                    ) maxts   ON r.OrganizationId = maxts.OrganizationId
                             AND r.Timestamp = maxts.Timestamp
          ) latest ON a.OrganizationId = latest.OrganizationId
     JOIN user as u ON u.Id = r.UserId
     JOIN etc.
```

Because you're joining activity, user, and organization you may still get tonnage of rows in this result set. But at least your review aggregates will be OK.

Note that you were bitten by the notorious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`.  Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Pro tip. Don't use `*` in SELECTs with `JOIN` operations. Nothing good can come from it. `*` returns duplicate id columns, and it tricks you into thinking you understand what you're joining, when you probably don't. In this case, you definitely don't because of your misuse of the `GROUP BY` extension.   As a professional programmer, you owe it to these users you're reviewing to be diligent in your understanding.

Comment: Yes I was going to count all non null values taht's why I didnt use DISTINCT, but thank you for the help with aggregates. It helped a lot, but I am still having issues with last line: JOIN user as u ON u.Id = r.UserId because it does not joins user neither activity if I try